# Passing arguments from one script to another

Tags: bash, scripting, variable, arguments

Let's say I am in a Bash script and am sourcing a file. How do I pass variables to another script after I source the file like this.

```
sed -i 's/ = /=/' $file
source $file
```

Let's say file contains

```
variable1=10
variable2=apple
```

If I want to use these in another script, how do I pass these arguments to the other script, then run the script in my current Bash script.

Comment: please also read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5228345/4023950

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would pass them pretty much the same as you would pass arguments in any other way:

```
sed -i 's/ = /=/' "$file"
source "$file"

/path/to/another/script.sh "$variable1" "$variable2"
```

Obviously using the appropriate command line switches (or not if applicable).

If using the code as above, the value of `$variable1` will be available in the other script as `$1` (the 1st command line argument), while `$variable2` will be available as `$2`.

To keep the original names in your new script you would need to reassign them using the positional parameters, ie:

```
variable1=$1
variable2=$2
```

However this may not be the most efficient way to do this, you might be better off with the suggestion below:

---

It sounds like you may actually want to source your file within the second script and not the first.  In which case you may want to do the following:

script1.sh:

```
sed -i 's/ = /=/' "$file"
/path/to/another/script2.sh "$file"
```

script2.sh:

```
file=$1
source "$file"
printf '%s\n' "$variable1"
printf '%s\n' "$variable2"
```

Related recommended reading: [3.4.1 Positional Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters)

> Note:  assigning `$1` to the `file` variable is not necessary, you could also simply `source "$1"` but I have written it this way in an attempt to show how positional parameters are handled

Comment: I tried this (no necessary switches) and it's not working. The "another" script is running, because if I set the other script simply to "echo apple", it will display "apple", but if I set the other script to simply "echo $variable1", it displays a blank line. I know $variable1 has a value, because if I do "echo $variable1" before calling the other script, I get the proper value, so it seems that the variable is not getting passed.

Comment: Is there something I need to do in the second script to *receive* $variable1 ?

Comment: lol why is the last part hidden? Is it a spoiler? XD

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't too many variables you want to pass, it's reasonable to just set them on the line where you call the subscript:

```
sed -i 's/ = /=/' "$file"
source "$file"

variable1=$variable1 variable2=$variable2 /path/to/another/script.sh
```